# How do I stroke a circle path with an arrow brush?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to draw a cirlce and stroke it with an arrow style brush.  I want to arrows to rotate along with the circle and not all stay the same direction.  Can I do this in photoshop?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers. If I understand you correctly: do you want a circle with _one_ arrowhead, or do you want a repeated arrowhead around a circle (kinda like some of the recycling-icons used).

Comment: ...and I think, in either case, Illustrator or Inkscape would be better tools for this.

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here - I think this is better solved in illustrator. There you have a few options.

You can make your own brush. Create the arrow-bit, make it a brush, and draw circles to your hearts content.

Other: you can use the already existing brushes (or look around the net for others):

[image]

If you *have to* make your arrow-shape yourself, here is what you can do. Draw the shape. Select the rotation tool, and, with the help of some guidelines such as helping lines or a circle, place the rotation point in the centre.

[image]

alt-click to get the rotation tool options, choose a degree, and choose copy. Then by pressing command + D, you duplicate the shape around the (imaginary or not) circle:

[image]